Dependency Injection into Community Toolkit Visual Studio Extension ToolWindow is not working
If I create a regular VSIX project(not a community one)

add a tool window,

and then add Autofac Dependency Injection infrastructure. This works fine as expected.
I basically picked up the idea from this article by Akos Nagy.
My full working example is here.
Note the tool window is derived from ToolWindowPane and it has a dependency on the UserControl as follows.
public class TrialToolWindow : ToolWindowPane
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TrialToolWindow"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public TrialToolWindow(TrialToolWindowControl trialToolWindowControl) : base(null)
    {
        this.Caption = "TrialToolWindow";

        // This is the user control hosted by the tool window; Note that, even if this class implements IDisposable,
        // we are not calling Dispose on this object. This is because ToolWindowPane calls Dispose on
        // the object returned by the Content property.
        this.Content = trialToolWindowControl;
    }
}

But then, I wanted to explore the same with community tool kit extension packages.
So I created a Community tool kit project with Toolwindow as follows. This is different from the above.

Note here the tool window derives from Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit.BaseToolWindow and looks as follows.
public class MyToolWindow : BaseToolWindow<MyToolWindow>
{

}

In this case again, the tool window has a dependency on User Control, and if it is hard coded(no DI) then it works fine.
Now I want to add Autofac infrastructure, and here is where the problem begins. The tool window does not show up. My project for this case is here
As tried to dig deeper into the BaseToolWindow class, I found that the problem is here when an object is newed up as follows.
_package = package;
_implementation = new T() { Package = package };

We know newing up stuff like that is a cardinal sin in DI, so I think is the problem.
But I am not sure the community development team did a mistake?
Or am I missing something here?
Is there some other/better way to do DI, that I am missing here?

Hi, I would suggest you could also confirm this issue at /Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit Issue

You mean, I should poste this there as well?

Added it here

Looks like that  the link of  your full working example is here and My project for this case is here returns 404 page not found.

@DouXu-MSFT, sorry about that. Please  check now.

Sorry , i have no  good idea about this issue now. Let's see if other members have any suggestions.
